# What are the drawbacks of session replication on Tomcat?

Tags: session, tomcat, replication

I was trying to decide what is better in a Tomcat+Apache reverse proxy mode for session replication. What is more common on deployments? session replication or stick session? Are there any drawbacks for session replication?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to 'session replication' across multiple clustered Tomcat servers so that session can failover?

Comment: Yes! I'm wondering what is better, session replication or stick session and their drawbacks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can point out the following considerations if you go for session replication.

**Performance**

The main drawback will be on performance. Replicated sessions involve copying of session data over to all the servers in the cluster. The more servers you have in the cluster, the additional overheads involved.

Tomcat helps with this overhead by definining two modes for session replication.

DeltaManager (default) and BackupManager

From this URL http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html

> Using the above configuration will
> enable all-to-all session replication
> using the DeltaManager to replicate
> session deltas. By all-to-all we mean
> that the session gets replicated to
> all the other nodes in the cluster.
> This works great for smaller cluster
> but we don't recommend it for larger
> clusters(a lot of tomcat nodes). Also
> when using the delta manager it will
> replicate to all nodes, even nodes
> that don't have the application
> deployed.
>
> To get around this problem,
> you'll want to use the BackupManager.
> This manager only replicates the
> session data to one backup node, and
> only to nodes that have the
> application deployed. Downside of the
> BackupManager: not quite as battle
> tested as the delta manager

Read [this URL](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/java_app/tomcat6/tomcat6_clustering.htm) for good design tips for the cluster if enabling session replication.

**Memory**

How many concurrent users will be hitting the application? the more users, the more data gets stored into sessions, and hence an overload for session replication.

**Code considerations**

Additionally you need to ensure the data being put into the session by the application is serializable. Serializing session data has some overhead for replicating the session state. It's a good idea to keep the session size reasonably small, so the developers need to check the amount of data being put into the session.

**Sticky Sessions**

Given these considerations, it actually depends on the criticality of the use cases. If you go for sticky sessions alone, then there is a chance of loss of user data during a critical journey.

Do you have means to recover from that - eg: by persisiting critical data into database at each step of a order or payment journey? If not the user has to login and start again. This is fine for websites which are not transactional, but browse brochureware type of data or filling out forms to capture data which is not payment etc.

Comment: Let us say we have session replication set up in tomcat. While the replication of a session is in progress, a request comes to a node which is not aware of the session (as replication is not complete). In such a case, what does tomcat do ? Does it hold the request till session replication completes or just proceed with the request ?